# Excel. Looking for exact match and return value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 Excel files. *Excel file 1* and *Excel file 2* contains:

- Fixed data in column A
- Different values in column H.

*Excel file 3* (dashboard) contains the fixed data found in column A of the 2 files, and column B, C, D should return the values of column H.

The data in column A can be moved to different cells so it should search for the exact match regardless of cell.

**Excel File 1**

```
Col. A          Col. H                                    
Thomas Moore        0
Albert Einstein    23
John Doe            8
```

**Excel File 2**

```
Col. A          Col. H                                    
Thomas Moore       10
Albert Einstein    98
John Doe           50
```

**Excel File 3**

```
Col. A          Col. B     Col. C                                    
Thomas Moore        0        10
Albert Einstein    23        98
John Doe            8        50
```

Column A (Same values in Excel file 1 and Excel file 2)
Column B (Excel file 1 Col H) 
Column C (Excel file 2 Col H)

In file 3, everytime it matches the exact values in other files Col A, it returns the corresponding value in H (works like a summary worksheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vlookup in File 3. If the first row has column labels, and the first column is in row 2, use this formula in B2

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[File 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$H$1000,8,FALSE)
```

In C2 use

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[File 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$H$1000,8,FALSE)
```

Adjust the number of rows in the formula to your data set and copy the formulas down.

Comment: I applied this =vlookup(A2;'[File 1.xlsx]Summary of Main'!A:A,8,false) and error message   what does 8,false means? it is highlighting this

Comment: I don't think you can use whole columns in Excel 2007 for Vlookup. Try to use a range with a limited number of rows. `8` instructs to return the value from the 8th column of the table (column H) and `False` is the instruction for an approximate match. You want an exact match, so the parameter needs to be `False`.

Comment: i used this =VLOOKUP(A2;'[File 1.xlsx]Summary of Main'!$A$2:$A$6;8;FALSE) and now giving me #REF! in B2 cell

Comment: You need to include the whole table not just $A$2:$A$6.  Excel looks for the 8th column and this only has one column so it fails.  Change that range to $A$2:$H$6.

Comment: My formula says `$A$1:$H$1000`, not `$A$1:$A$1000`. Why don't you start with the formula I supplied and just change the file and sheet name? Every other change you make will be likely to break the formula.

Comment: Thanks all...is there a way to put icons to Column B, C, D to signify increasing, decreasing or equal from the prior cell  example B2 23 then in C2 98 so in C2 cell I need an icon which shows increase

Comment: Please don't ask a new question in a comment. If you have a new question, ask a new question.